# BufferedReader read too many times

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I can't understand because this piece of code read too many times the file. The same code, with a CSV with a special char as separator, works great...but with a CSV with ; as separator reads too many times the same file.

Here the cose:

```
public static ArrayList<Asset> retriveCIInstances(File sap_csv_source, String parseChar) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("PARSING WITH THE CHAR: " + parseChar);
    ArrayList<Asset> res = new ArrayList<Asset>();      
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(sap_csv_source);        
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine; 
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        System.out.println("LINE CSV: " + strLine);
        String[] raw = strLine.split(parseChar);
        res.add(new Asset(null,raw[1],raw[0],raw[8], null,null));
    }
    in.close();
    fstream.close();
    return res;
}
```

and the two files content are:
(doesn't work)

```
ASSET_TAG;SAP Purchase Order number;SAP Purchase Order position number;Asset Type;Asset Category;Asset description;Manufacturer;Model;Serial Number;Location ID;Delivery Note number;Delivery note date;EOF
B1CSSW01SN78JJNYU76U;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C2960-24LT-L;SN78JJNYU76U;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
B1CSSW01SNRU7687JUIUJ;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C2960-24LT-L;SNRU7687JUIUJ;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
B1CSSW01SNFGH6765Y66;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C2960-24LT-L;SNFGH6765Y66;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
B1CSSW01SN3435REG45Y;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C2960-24LT-L;SN3435REG45Y;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
```

or 
(works)

```
 ASSET_TAG¤SAP Purchase Order number¤SAP Purchase Order position number¤Asset Type¤Asset Category¤Asset description¤Manufacturer¤Model¤Serial Number¤Location ID¤Delivery Note number¤Delivery note date¤EOF
B1HPDT06SN345TREG5Y¤4500117819¤10¤Desktop¤Workstation¤¤HP¤8200 Elite SFF Standard¤SN345TREG5Y¤X-RM-0047_04¤TEST_HW00_11FEB14|17|4500117819-10¤11/02/2014¤EOF
B1HPDT06SN56654GHTD¤4500117819¤10¤Desktop¤Workstation¤¤HP¤8200 Elite SFF Standard¤SN56654GHTD¤X-RM-0047_04¤TEST_HW00_11FEB14|17|4500117819-10¤11/02/2014¤EOF
B1HPDT06SNGJ987IKJJH¤4500117819¤10¤Desktop¤Workstation¤¤HP¤8200 Elite SFF Standard¤SNGJ987IKJJH¤X-RM-0047_04¤TEST_HW00_11FEB14|17|4500117819-10¤11/02/2014¤EOF
B1HPDT06SN65765HT56¤4500117819¤10¤Desktop¤Workstation¤¤HP¤8200 Elite SFF Standard¤SN65765HT56¤X-RM-0047_04¤TEST_HW00_11FEB14|17|4500117819-10¤11/02/2014¤EOF
```

And the output is:

```
 LINE CSV: ASSET_TAG;SAP Purchase Order number;SAP Purchase Order position
;Asset Type;Asset Category;Asset description;Manufacturer;Model;Serial Num
cation ID;Delivery Note number;Delivery note date;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN78JJNYU76U;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN78JJNYU76U;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNRU7687JUIUJ;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C29
T-L;SNRU7687JUIUJ;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;E
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNFGH6765Y66;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SNFGH6765Y66;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN3435REG45Y;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN3435REG45Y;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: ASSET_TAG;SAP Purchase Order number;SAP Purchase Order position
;Asset Type;Asset Category;Asset description;Manufacturer;Model;Serial Num
cation ID;Delivery Note number;Delivery note date;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN78JJNYU76U;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN78JJNYU76U;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNRU7687JUIUJ;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C29
T-L;SNRU7687JUIUJ;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;E
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNFGH6765Y66;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SNFGH6765Y66;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN3435REG45Y;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN3435REG45Y;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: ASSET_TAG;SAP Purchase Order number;SAP Purchase Order position
;Asset Type;Asset Category;Asset description;Manufacturer;Model;Serial Num
cation ID;Delivery Note number;Delivery note date;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN78JJNYU76U;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN78JJNYU76U;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNRU7687JUIUJ;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C29
T-L;SNRU7687JUIUJ;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;E
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNFGH6765Y66;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SNFGH6765Y66;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN3435REG45Y;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN3435REG45Y;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: ASSET_TAG;SAP Purchase Order number;SAP Purchase Order position
;Asset Type;Asset Category;Asset description;Manufacturer;Model;Serial Num
cation ID;Delivery Note number;Delivery note date;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN78JJNYU76U;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN78JJNYU76U;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNRU7687JUIUJ;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C29
T-L;SNRU7687JUIUJ;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;E
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SNFGH6765Y66;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SNFGH6765Y66;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
LINE CSV: B1CSSW01SN3435REG45Y;4500136741;20;Switch;Network;;Cisco;WS-C296
-L;SN3435REG45Y;X-MAG-VIRTUA;TEST11FEB2014|17|4500136741-20;11/02/2014;EOF
```

for four lines it prints a lot of lines...I don't understand.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show all your code. In particular, you're returning a `List<Asset>`; is the caller then printing the contents? Additionally, using `try-with-resources` is a better approach than manually closing your streams, but even if you do need to close them manually, calling `br.close()` will cause all of the streams it's built on to be closed.

Comment: I've tried your code, it works. The only thing I changed was to comment out `res.add(new Asset(null,raw[1],raw[0],raw[8], null,null));` because I don't know what the Asset class is. Something must be happening in there.

Comment: The problem is before the return...the System.out print the full ile (line by line) too many times as you can see (just see the header that is printed X times).

Comment: The code works when the CSV is separated with ¤ and it doens't work when is separated with ;. I don't understand

Comment: It is working even with ";" separated.. check the parseChar value when your processing ";" separated file.it should be parseChar=";" ...and giving me 5 lines as output...including header

Comment: I checked the parseChar: I print the separator: 
PARSING WITH THE CHAR: ";"

Comment: then i think problem is not here.. Am getting proper output just copy pasted your code and tested..Check the filename and its content which your supplying as input

Comment: you are right...it was a stupid problem...the file was written multiple times by an external source. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: ok thats why i said ..problem is not here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid problem...the file was written multiple times by an external source. Sorry for the inconvenience! I'm mortified